# Stop ItemCheckedIn from calling from within ItemCheckingIn in SharePoint event receiver

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I was wondering whether it is possible to stop ItemCheckedIn from calling from within ItemCheckingIn?  I.e. I only want the item checked in action to be called when certain criteria is met in item checking in.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried `properties.Cancel = true;` on your event properties?

Take a look at this article it talks about event receivers and has a cancel example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252010.aspx